# Using 's for "ancestors"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Majumder grew up in the house of his _______.

- ancestors'
- ancestor

Which one of these should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Ancestors without the apostrophe is the correct usage in your given expression.

Other possible construction would have been, Person grew up in his ancestors' house.

Answer (score 1):

It’s quite common the “ancestors” word, because everyone has more than one ancestor. I think that ancestor can be used when you want to describe or say something specific of how your ancestor was.

Comment: Yes, but without the apostrophe, as Rohit says.

Comment: @KateBunting - if I can say 'I crashed a car of my father's', why can't I say I lived in a (or the) house of my ancestors'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Of course one's ancestors could well have lived in many different houses, just as Father could have owned several cars, but surely 'the house of my ancestors' usually implies a particular ancestral home?

Comment: @KateBunting - yes, one single home, like e.g. Castle Howard in North Yorkshire, England, which has been the home of the Carlisle branch of the Howard family for more than 300 years. It's not actually a castle.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - It wasn't very sensible of me to put the phrase in single inverted commas! I meant, of course _the house of my ancestors_ without apostrophe.

Comment: @KateBunting So you would advise against the plural possessive in _of my ancestors'_ ? Compare _the car of my father's_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I would understand _a car of my father's_ to mean 'one of the several cars he owns', but _the house of my ancestors_ to refer to one particular house.